# Hiding and Showing HTML Element using jQuery using :contains()

Tags: jquery

I have a unordered list inside a div tag that is hidden on ready:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>Title goes here</title>
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#great_bands').hide();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
```

then this DIV section:

```
<div id="great_bands">
   <h2>My Favorite Bands </h2>
   <ul id="band_list">
        <li> Metallica (1) </li>
        <li> Skid Row (2) </li>
       <li> AC/DC (3) </li>
   </ul>
 <span onclick="$('ul[li*="1"]').show()">1</span>
```

I need the `on click` to un-hide and show the band with the number (1) in the `<li>` section, but can't get it to work.  I've tried a bunch of different ways and can't figure it out (including a function at the onclick instead of the jQuery). It won't do anything when the (1) is clicked.

Added to clarify:

The list of bands is hidden when the user loads the page, but it needs to display it.  Additionally,  this is all my own code.  Nothing is pasted from my assignment as it was given as a word problem with no source provided. I also tried using a function call instead:

```
function showBandOne()
{

  $('ul[li*="1"]').show();
};
```

But this didn't work either.

Comment: Thanks!  I've been working on this part for hours and can't figure it out.   sigh.

Comment: Is it possible that you could add the number like (2) as an attribute to the `<li>` for instance `<li data-li-num="2">Skid Row (2)</li>` ?

Comment: JakeGould, I don't expect anyone to do my work for me.  I won't learn that way.  I thought I'd post here in case someone could point me in the right direction.  Sorry if that didn't come out right - I am just beyond frustrated.

Comment: @JakeGould - i don't agree with the -1. I think the question was written well enough to follow and to give constructive advice. I do agree that the title is horrid.

Comment: I can't suggest an Edit, but I would recommend... rewording the title too something like "Hiding HTML Element by contents" or "Cannot hide  a particular HTML Element on click".

Comment: I've read the question multiple times, but when I look at the code and the description, I just can't understand what needs to happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't set attributes of the `li` and the thing you want to click, then i think the best trick would be to use the `:contains()` selector like the following: http://jsfiddle.net/B4xKr/1/

```
$(function() {
    $(".show_band").click(function () {
        var num = $(this).text();
        $("ul#band_list li:contains( \(" + num + "\))").show();
    });
});
```

read more about `:contains()` https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

Comment: Thank you very much.   I will read the documentation for the :contains() selector right now.  The title was just a place holder. I try to get the hardest parts done first.

Comment: @user3555011 - I suggested the title "jQuery - selecting elements based on text content." If this answer, answers your question you should accept it, if not you should explain why it doesn't.

Comment: @user3555011 You don't need to rely on writing number inside your elements. Jquery can find out the index of each element. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/B4xKr/2/)

Answer (score 1):

jQuery..

```
jQuery('#click_me').click(function(e) {
    jQuery('div#greatbands').find('ul#band_list li:first-child').hide();
});
```

HTML

```
 <span id='click_me' style='cursor:pointer;'>Click Me</span>
```

I'd recommend using [browser inspection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector) functionality, and trying to `select` the `element` you want to modify with `jQuery`.. in `CSS`, For example... (it helps, when trying to figure out which `elements` jQuery will select, with the same `selector`).

```
 ul#band_list li:first-child { border:1px solid red; }
```

Also `ul[li*="1"]` is a selector that is referencing attributes on the `li` element, not contents. If you are referring to selecting an element based on its contents and not its attributes, then I'd recommend using [`:contains()`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) ([Victory](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1353934/victory), 2014).

Comment: Thanks for the cite Killrawr. If I extrapolate a bit on the question, it seems the user should, in fact, consider using custom attributes, paring the element to click with the element that should be shown. Answering exactly the question, your answer seems fit.

Comment: @Victory no problem, I've already given your answer +1 rep too :). regards